# Creating a conference with only one user via Lync api - Meet Now

Tags: lync, conference

I have been trying to build an application in the Lync sdk. What I want is to simulate a conference room environment where - the first user that comes in initiates a conference and puts the conference uri on the server for subsequent users to join - basically essentially the same functionality that the MEET NOW option of MS's Lync client exposes. However, what i have found out is that both the methods - beginstartconversation() in _Automation class and _LyncClient.ConversationManager.AddConversation(), only initiate P2P conversation nd u get a conference uri only when more than 2 users are joined in. I want a user to be able to host a conference without inviting any specific users. Is there any workaround?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this in the client side SDK.

One option would be to create a UCMA application that responds to an incoming conversation by escalating to a conference and returning the URI back to the user.

Your custom client could then start a conversation with your application and send an IM. The conversation would then be escalated to a conference, and the URI returned from the application as an IM. Your custom client could then handle the URI as it pleases.

The [UCMA SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=4493baab-6214-4770-8cf9-69c813e8a9fa) contains enough example code to get you up and running with this quickly

Comment: Ya i had been starting to feel the same, that you cant do it in lync sdk. Thanks a lot for your response and advice :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding a dummy user to the conference when you start it. The dummy can be any URI of the form: dumb@dumber.dum, a@b etc. The client SDK will automatically escalate to a conference call and remove the dummy user. The escalation will persist. Note that this will take some time, as it does in Microsoft's client as well.

Answer (score 1):

One method to simulate Meetnow in Lync is by using Automation Class in Lync SDK.

BeginMeetNow() will create a conference with IM Modality add Audio Video Modality to conference using BeginConnect().

```
Automation automation = LyncClient.GetAutomation();
automation.BeginMeetNow((ar) =>
{
    conferenceWindow = automation.EndMeetNow(ar);
    conference = conferenceWindow.Conversation;

    conference.Modalities[ModalityTypes.AudioVideo].BeginConnect((ar1) =>
    {
        conference.Modalities[ModalityTypes.AudioVideo].EndConnect(ar1);
    }, null);
}, null);
```

Lync SDK 2013 : https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=36824

Comment: The first answer was correct at the time of the question, however, with the release of the 2013 SDK, this now works.

Comment: Yes that is true, in UI suppressed mode even using lync 2013 sdk i was not able to find any other method other than adding dummy users.