# Creating a conference with Lync 2010 SDK

Tags: sdk, lync, lync-2010

I know that we can create conference calls with Outlook when Lync is also installed on the computer. I assume Lync SDK is used by this plugin.

Where should I look in the SDK to be able to create a conference call and then retrieve it's URL and rest of the metadata (using Lync client)?

### **Edit:**

I managed to create new conversation (with automation), but I can't find any way how to create conference or transform conversation into conference. I noticed that there are properties for conferencing, like URI but they are never set up.

Answer (score 1):

You can escalate to a conference by adding a dummy uri (a@b, dummy@dumber.dumb) to the participant list. This is easy for outgoing calls but has problems with incoming calls becuase you have to stop video and restart it at specific points in the escalation process else Lync hangs. Note that the escalation process takes some time, as it does in Microsoft's client, and that the dummy gets discarded while the escalation persists.

Answer (score 0):

You can't (I don't believe) escalate a conversation to a conference using the Lync SDK - you would have to use the UCMA SDK to do this.

There is a similar thread on this here: [Creating a conference with only one user via Lync api - Meet Now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423608/creating-a-conference-with-only-one-user-via-lync-api-meet-now)

Answer (score 0):

***regedit***

see xml element `ConfJoinLink` in PublicMeeting in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Communicator\ConfAddin\xxx@yyy.fr`

***sample:***

```
string confJoinLink = ...; //("conf:sip:xxx@yyy.fr;gruu;opaque=app:conf:focus:id:PK382RG3?conversation-id=w8YL86ez1f")

IAsyncResult ar = _automation.BeginStartConversation(confJoinLink, 0, StartConversationWithConferenceUriCallback, _automation);
```